What is a short <commit-ish> to a pull request?
I have a pull request I want to review locally in a git work tree:
$ git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head'
d4...   refs/pull/2/head

This pull request has a branch main. The documentation of git-worktree tells me that I can add a new worktree by using the following syntax:
add <path> [<commit-ish>]

Then again, a previous discussion on what is a <commit-ish> gives me at least the following alternatives for this ish-creature:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Commit-ish/Tree-ish   |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  <refname>             | master, heads/master, refs/heads/master
|  <refname>@{upstream}  | master@{upstream}, @{u}

What is the correct format for <commit-ish> for this pull request?
Every format I have tried so far has failed.

Your question should remain strictly a question. Perhaps your recent edits should be an answer instead?

@tripleee Done, although it is not really an answer but a set of workarounds found so far.

After the command
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head'

You only know that one of the commits is
d4...    refs/pull/2/head

on the remote server. To inspect the commit locally, you must first download it. You can use git fetch to do so:
git fetch origin refs/pull/2/head

The output of the command will tell you where it stored the commit locally, something like:
* branch                  refs/pull/2/head -> FETCH_HEAD

The commit is now available under the name FETCH_HEAD. This is not a branch name, but a so-called pseudo-ref and is not listed among the git branch output.
You can now use this name as the commit-ish:
git worktree add ~/tmp/pr-2-review FETCH_HEAD

Note, since FETCH_HEAD is not a branch name, the worktree that is created in this manner is now in detached HEAD mode. You could make changes and commits there, but they are not on any branch until you create a branch that points at that commit.
So, what is a commit-ish now? A commit-ish is any form of reference that ultimately resolves to a commit ID. Examples are a branch name, remote tracking branch name, tag name, full or abbreviated SHA1, pseudo-ref, and any ref expressions constructed from these.

Your reply suggests that the problem is the fact that the info is on the remote server. However, first, the output of git ls-remote links the pull request to a commit id, and this commit id can be used directly to create a correct work tree (see edit in OP). No explicit link to remote is necessary. Second, <commit-ish> can include @{upstream}; shouldn't this provide a way to access the needed info from the remote?

Additionally, git pull can work directly using the remote symbolic name, so shouldn't this also apply to git worktree add?

@jhu Git is intended to work only with the local repository. There're very few commands that query/exchange data with distant (I don't use the word "remote" here to avoid confusion with locally stored URLs) repositories: archive, clone, fetch, ls-remote, pull, push, remote are the only ones I know. @{upstream} doesn't use info from the distant repo, it uses only locally stored info. Whatever you haven't fetched locally — isn't available for commands.

@phd Have I undestood this correctly: Call to ls-remote has accessed the remote server and stored locally the info that the distant commit id d4... exists, so that it can be used to add a new work tree (see OP). However, ls-remote has not stored the info that refs/pull/2/head is a symbolic name to this commit id? And this is why I can use the commit id but not the symbolic name?

@jhu No, ls-remote doesn't not stored the info; actually it doesn't not stored any info; no more than ls with local files. git fetch (or pull) store that info — they fetch commits and update references; they're the only commands that update remote-tracking references (plus push and remote update).

Ok, so git fetch stores locally the info about the existence of commit id d4... but not of the existence of the symbolic name refs/pull/2/head, and this is why the commit id can be used by git worktree add but not the symbolic name can not be used. I have to admit that understanding this requires very detailed technical info, that is, what is stored locally and what is not.

The answer above shows exact commands to do. I usually do git fetch origin refs/pull/2/head:pr-2 && git checkout pr-2; or in your case git worktree add ~/tmp/pr-2-review pr-2.

According to the responses so far, there does not seem to be a short <commit-ish> that could be used directly with git worktree add. This is because git worktree add only uses locally stored info. As the answer and the comments above show, there seems to be at least two ways around this.
Method 1: use commit id
[Using just git fetch removed per the comments]
Method 2: create a pseudo-ref for the pull request
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/2/head
From github.com:...
 * branch            refs/pull/2/head -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git worktree add ~/tmp/pr-2-review FETCH_HEAD
Preparing worktree (detached HEAD d4...)
HEAD is now at d4...

Then, when you are done reviewing the request
$ git worktree remove ~/tmp/pr-2-review

Method 3: create a branch for the pull request
This requires deleting the created branch afterwards, so it is a bit more work.
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/2/head:pr-2
From github.com:...
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/2/head -> pr-2
$ git worktree add ~/tmp/pr-2-review pr-2
Preparing worktree (checking out 'pr-2')
HEAD is now at d4...

Then, after reviewing:
$ git worktree remove ~/tmp/pr-2-review/
$ git branch -D pr-2
Deleted branch pr-2 (was d4...).


Method 1 does not work as written, because in a normal clone the remote refs/pull namespace is not configured to be fetched. Extra steps would be needed to fetch the ref without being named with the git fetch command. Method 3 works because refs/pull/2/head is mentioned as command argument.

@j6t What might be the extra steps required for method 1? The typescript of the method is from a terminal session, so I am trying to understand what makes that session special.

If the dump is to be taken literally, then you see that there is no output of git fetch. Since the subsequent git worktree add still worked, you have the commit already available locally, presumably from earlier experiments. The extra steps needed would be to configure that refs/pull is fetched from the remote: git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*' (The part pull-requests can be anything of your choice.)

@j6t Good point: I cloned a fresh repo, and method 1 did not work immediately. But a following fetch with refs/pull/2/head also updated the info on the needed commit id for method 1. I did not find a way to specify namespace from the command line, so at least for the time being I will edit away method 1. Thanks!
